# Spring (3.1.0) controller validation is not working

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm using Spring 3.1.0, and have a few `@Controller` classes, running on Tomcat.

I use the class-level `@Validated` annotation in order to enable validations, and I defined some constraints on the controller-methods parameters.

A code example is here:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/chapters")
public class ChapterController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    protected Chapter get(@RequestParam @Min(1) @Max(10) count) {
        return getChapters(count);
    }

}
```

Even though annotations are defined are required, the validation is not happening, so that when I pass an invalid value (for example: count=15), nothing happens and the handler is running the value.

I expect some exception will be thrown on invalid function parameters,
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: are you using Spring boot?

Comment: No. Only spring framework.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling parameter validation also requires a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean.
Since you are not using a Spring Boot, you need to add this bean explicitly.(With Spring Boot , this bean is auto-configured if you have the `hibernate-validator` dependency on classpath).

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("yourpackage")
public class ClientWebConfigJava implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Got it. And this bean should be added to application-context.xml? is there any specific id for it?

Comment: @Forepick Yes, you add this bean `<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>` in `application-context.xml`. See this example : https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-rest/request-body-parameter-validation/ or checkout documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html section **7.8 Spring Validation**

Comment: Well nope. Still not working. Not with MethodValidationPostProcessor and not with LocalValidatorFactoryBean as in the example

Comment: @Forepick Do you have JSR-303/JSR-349 provider, such as Hibernate Validator, in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, I have hibernate-validator on my pom.xml

Comment: @Forepick What is the type of your variable `count`? I don't see that you have specified variable type.. I guess it should be `Integer`

Comment: @Forepick Try to add beans in `spring-servlet.xml` (spring context) not `application-context.xml`

Comment: Yes, count is Integer. missed it here. I don't have any spring-servlet.xml, but rather rest-context.xml or RestDispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: @Forepick  Ok then try to create `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean as Java class, as I described in my answer above. If that doesn't work, than declare the bean in your `rest-context.xml` file

Comment: still nothing. I set the @ComponentScan value to the package where all my rest controllers are